# jQuery - find the id is existing in iframe condition fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am generating the `iframe` and its `id` dynamically.

Now I have a situation to find if the `Id` is already existing or not.

My code will be,

```
function createIframe(intxnId){

    alert("Id is : "+"$('#"+intxnId+"')");

    if($("'#ch"+intxnId+"'").length == 0){
        alert("Creating the new Iframe intxnId is: " +intxnId);
        var iframe = "<iframe id='ch"+intxnId+"' src='" + contexPath + "/HeartChat.html?intxnId="+intxnId+"' class='iframeSize'></iframe>";
        alert("iFrame Details : "+iframe);

        $("#chatMessageArea").find("#messageArea").html(iframe);

    }else{
        alert("ID is already present !");
    }
}
```

My alert for the dynamic Id is ,

[image]

But I got the error as,

[image]

Good answers are definitely appreciated !

Comment: `$("'#ch"+intxnId+"'")` - change this to `$("#ch"+intxnId)`

Comment: But this leads to get an Id without quotes like `$(#ch0012004p)`.But the proper format is `$('#ch0012004p')` only know ?

Comment: try it at firebug and it will work.

Comment: @KitePlayer, you don't need quotes if you are using a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery selector is invalid, for some reason it is wrapped in single quotes. Change to:

```
if($("#ch"+intxnId).length == 0){
```

Currently your selector evaluates to:

```
$("'#chXYZ'") // wrong, it should evaluate to $("#chXYZ")
```

Also, there is no code in your question that could produce the alert shown.

Comment: Can u please explain why jquery assumes like this. But I am getting the alert like this `$('#chXYZ')` only

Comment: The string only needs a single set of quotes, it's not just jQuery, the whole Javascript language behaves the same - if you put single quotes within a double quoted string, the single quotes will remain a literal part of the string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Then why we get the element like `$('#chXYZ').hide()` or sometheing ?

Comment: That works because you only wrap the string in a single set of quotes. It doesn't matter if they are double or single quotes so `$('#chXYZ').hide()` is the same as `$("#chXYZ").hide(). But if you add another set of quotes inside either of those, it will no longer work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then if I used `if($("#ch"+intxnId).length == 0)` what it assumes. My view is there is no quotes in the selector.It produces `$(#ch230p75)` . Does it work ?

Comment: The code will work yes, but it's not evaluated as `$(#ch230p75)`, think of it more like $(myStringHere). Javascript is passing a string variable defined as `"#ch230p75"`.

Comment: Thanks for your support `MrCode` and I will accept your answer and `+1` for you.